# Set environment variable for X tray

Tags: linux, xorg, i3, hidpi

I want to set `GDK_SCALE` and `GDK_DPI_SCALE` environment variables for the entire system (to deal with HiDPI) except the process that's in charge of X tray icons. I'm struggling to figure out what's the lower-level process that's in charge of that. I have Lightdm + i3 but I'm not sure which one's in charge of X.

Comment: base on linux distribution but for centos `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile`

Comment: I've currently put it in `~/.profile` but lightdm sources that before starting X

Comment: `~/.profile` is for user level, those mentioned by me are system wide